# Initialization order of static variables

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to confirm whether static variable initialization in Objective-C works the same as it does for C++.  Specifically do static variables have the possibility of being instantiated/created before main() is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no concept of instantiation of static variables in Objective-C proper. e.g.

```
// file level
NSMutableArray* foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

is not allowed. It's the same as in C: you can only initialize static variables with constants. For Objective-C objects, that means `nil` or literal strings.

In Objective-C++, you can do that, and they are called before `main()`. It just follows C++'s part of the rules of Objective-C++.

When you want to initialize objects associated to a class in Objective-C, you use `+initialize` or `+load`. See this [nice blog article](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html).